# GWT DatePicker Locale

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, localization, locale

is possible to set a Locale for com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DatePicker?
I need to show the days and the weeks in italian style.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [datepicker widget](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-datepicker/) for gwt that handle [locale](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-datepicker/wiki/HowToUse).

The [demo](http://datepickerdemo.appspot.com/?locale=it_IT) for italian locale.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: demo link does not work anymore, next time put the code in your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for [`DatePicker`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DatePicker.html) has an example that should get you started - you just have to format the date using [`DateTimeFormat`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) in a `ValueChangeHandler` assigned to your `DatePicker`:

```
public class DatePickerExample implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Create a date picker
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    final Label text = new Label();

    // Set the value in the text box when the user selects a date
    datePicker.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler() {
      public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        Date date = event.getValue();
        String dateString = DateTimeFormat.getMediumDateFormat().format(date);
        text.setText(dateString);
      }
    });

    // Set the default value
    datePicker.setValue(new Date(), true);

    // Add the widgets to the page
    RootPanel.get().add(text);
    RootPanel.get().add(datePicker);
  }
}
```

This will format the date in your default locale - if you want to change it to something else, there'a [whole section](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html) on how you can do it in the GWT docs.

Answer (score 0):

Locales in GWT are set global.

You can set the local e.g. in a meta tag in your html file:

```
<html><head><meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=it">...
```

and you have to add the locale to the modulefile *.gwt.xml:

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="it"/>
```

The properties are defined here:

com.google.gwt.i18n.client.constants.DateTimeConstantsImpl_xx.properties

For more, read the documentation.